# navigation bar list width

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I am creating a navigation bar right now and I want the width of the main elements on the navigation to be auto, but sub elements to all be a fixed width. The way the list is made is as such:

```
    <li>Main Element
        <ul>
        <li> Sub Element </li>
        <li> Sub Element </li>
        <li> Sub Element </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

This is repeated for each main menu item and its submenu items.

The issue I am having is I want to css for the sub elements to be 100px in width, but the main elements to be equal to the text size plus 10px of padding on both the left and right. It appears I can not change one without changing both, even after attempting to make classes to separate them. I have also tried editting `ul li` and `li ul` styles in my external style sheet. Thank you in advance for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ul li` affects all `li`'s at any level under an `ul`. `ul > li` only affects the `li`'s that are direct children of an `ul`. It's called a child combinator: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators

You must use it if you are to make it happen without using classes (using classes would actually be the better way imo - http://www.jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/xeWA4 )

The trick is applying the styles you want applied on the main menu items under `ul > li` and then override them at `ul ul > li`. Here's a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/xeWA4/3/

**EDIT:**
You actually don't need to use the child combinator at all. Child combinators came to my mind
when I first read your question, and I kind of never questioned their use. So, `ul li` overridden by `ul ul li` works perfectly as well - and keeps it simpler.

Comment: I thought so as well, however the entire navigation is within a `ul` tag, so to clarify, it goes `<ul> <li> main <ul> <li> sub </li> </ul> </li> </ul>` is the outermost ul tag unnecessary? And how could I style this; to my understanding `style="width:1em; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;"` should work, but it wasn't before, maybe because of the outermost ul.

Comment: And here's how I'd do it without adding classes (as you were doing it): http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/xeWA4/2/ . It becomes very confusing and probably hard to mantain. That's why I wouldn't do it this way.

Comment: That didn't really work, but I think I've mixed up my css a fair bit. Atm I have to call it a night, I'll try cleaning it up and trying it properly tomorrow and see if it works. If i can get it to work I'll accept the answer, if not I'll have more questions. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, I'll be here tomorrow ;)